# DFF - Digital Forensic Framework console mode

Tags: forensics

I have a question about DFF - Digital Forensic Framework. More precisely, about its console mode.

I know, that there is GUI mode, but i need console mode for using it via php in my web-application.

So, when i use dff --help, i see really not very useful information. 
Also, project's wiki is down right now: http://wiki.digital-forensic.org/

I need DFF to open some .raw images and export some existing and deleted files from it. But i need to do this using console mode. And i have no idea how to do this, and where i can get some documentation about DFF console mode.

Maybe someone worked with this framework, or knows where to find the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I am not familiar with DFF, but I use the `Sleuthkit`. It can do what you ask to do - *open* the raw image, identify the filesystem, show you the list of files, and extract existing and (if possible) deleted files. You need not to build your own web interface, because you can use `Autopsy` package. So you can work remotely. The features and stability grows, and it is well documented. It can also work directly with EWF forensic evidence format what can you save some disk space and somtimes the most of your evidence data (if the storage particulary fails).

Comment: The link you showed does not hit. Some information about the DFF I found at Kali - Linux site (kali.org).